# VS 2017 can't work once i open *axml file

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

I installed Xamarin in Vs 2017 installer and the Android SDK tools version is 26.1.1 and the Android platform-Tools the Android build-tools is latest. I heave reset many times but it doesn't work on me. The CPU occupancy rate is 40%~30% once I open * axml file but there just blank in the design page.

[image: this is the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Atm it's not supporting it, just right-click filename and choose Edit With - Code Editor.

Comment: What is Atm?I want use designer.

Comment: why I can't open *axml file as Android Designer

Comment: xamarin and vs for windows are not supporting this feature at the moment, lets pray for the future.

Comment: but I have see a lot blog can open it and can add button visually, not in Code editor

Comment: might work on Mac, not Windows development environment

Comment: I have update vs2017,it still blank when I open a *axml in Layout Designer.